# Angular Universal Node Modules Giving window/.addeventlistener

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I make angular application now i am trying to converting it in angular universal so there is lot of package i used now i am getting lot of error related to window.addeventListener or getUserMedia undefined but this events is not available in code its coming from packages so please share idea how can i load modules after reloading or how can i resolve these issue.

i tried changes and removing node packages but that is not the good solution if we can load node modules after rendering or client side for support then it is better

Comment: `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object` then use the following check for browser-only code: `if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Angular SSR is running in a server and not in a web browser.
Because of this, Angular SSR does not have access to web APIs, such as window dot ..., document dot ..., localstorage dot ...

As far as I know, you have two solutions.

The first is to do if/else in your Angular code in order to tell SSR (Hey Angular, this piece of code should only be executed on the server side (SSR) or on the browser side.

To do so
you can use PLATFORM_ID (This will allow you to know, programmatically if the code is being executed on the browser side or on the server side)

Second option:

Use a server-side package that will "mock" the browser api.
An example: https://www.danywalls.com/angular-and-domino-a-powerful-combo-for-server-side-rendering